# Content provider with internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, internal-storage

I'm writing an app in which I'm saving photos in internal storage. I'm using solution from this **[blog](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.com/2012/04/save-captured-image-to-applications.html)**

I know names of two files before, so I can have in a code, but in my app there will be also a gallery. So my question is: how to save files without knowing their name(file name is generated using date and time)? Content provider's oncreate starts during initialisation so how to pass new files names to content provider?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I'm using solution from this blog` Have you got that example to work?

Comment: Yes, but in this example filename is hardcoded inside custom ContentProvider.

Comment: Well I cannot get it to work. Moreover I do not understand the code. First I have to get it to work. Did you have any problems with it?

Comment: None, everything is working like a charm.

Comment: Got it to work. Now before answering your question I would like to know if you are going to use the content provider for other actions also. Later on in your app?

Comment: So I would also like to know why you use a content provider to begin with. The blog states: `Now assume that in your device there is no sd-card present. ohh no, Your application will not work` But that's nonsence as there is always external memory present. So you could save to external memory yourself using what the blog calls `The first solution`. Only when you really want the media store to save to your app's internal/private memory you need a content provider solution.

Comment: Currently I'm using content provider only for taking photos and store them in internal storage, then display in gridview. It's better not to use external storage, because app I'm working on should be able to display photos all the time. And using external storage isn't good for ie. user will remove sdcard.

Comment: I have two actions with camera. The first one is simple because I'm saving to files with names I know and I can create them during oncreate. The second action is a camera action with taking high quality photos and display them in gridview and show high resolution image after item click.

Comment: Sorry. But I'm not interested in actions with the camera as well in actions with the content provider. So you will use the content provider only when taking some pictures. Not when placing them in a gridview and not for uploading to some server or to deliver to an external app or something like that. How does the gridview know which pictures there are in internal files dir?

Comment: Further I have to admit that I was wrong with external files dir. Indeed there are devices which have external files dir on removable media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the content provider class remove in onCreate the file creation completely.

```
public static String lastPictureSaved = "";
```

Change the function `openFile`. There the filename will be made accordig to date time and the file created.

```
 Date date = new Date();     
 date.getTime();
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
 String datetimestr = formatter.format(date);       
 lastPictureSaved = getContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + datetimestr + ".jpg";        
 File f = new File(lastPictureSaved);

 try
   {
    f.createNewFile();
   }
 catch (IOException e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();

    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
   }
```

in the Host activity change

```
 File out = new File(getFilesDir(), "newImage.jpg");
```

to

```
 File out = new File(MyFileContentProvider.lastPictureSaved);
```

Comment: I have one more question. After changes I cannot use my previous version with hardcoded filenames. How to add to this condition from which activity content provider was called? Then time stamp will be used only from gallery and filenames ie. newImage only from another.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you exactly want. You want to call it from another activity? You want to use the content privider not only for taking snap shots but also for other thing? Well I asked you right away if you were going to use the content provider for other things. And you never gave a satisfying answer.

Comment: I'm using content provider for taking photos only. Basically, I have two activities: in first one I have capture one photo action with hardcoded filename "partner.jpg", so it's the same code as in that blog post. Second activity is a gridview with images with time stamp filename. My question is how to handle these two options in content provider?

Comment: Add another static variable to your class. Like `public static String theCaller = "";` Set it before you take a picture like `MyFileContentProvider.theCaller = "ActivityA";` Then in openFile() inspect 'theCaller' and act accordingly. You can even put the filename there. Or just put a filename or an empty filename with something like `MyFileContentProvider.theFileName = "alittlepicture.jpg"`. or `MyFileContentProvider.theFileName = ""` and inspect theFileName in openFile(). So you have a way to let the provider determine the filename or the activity. What do you want more?